# Unity 5, Bundle scene without dependencies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity 5.6, when calling

```
public static AssetBundleManifest BuildAssetBundles(string outputPath, AssetBundleBuild[] builds, BuildAssetBundleOptions assetBundleOptions, BuildTarget targetPlatform);
```

where a scene is in one of the builds, all dependencies/references in that scene will automatically be included.

I have a situation where a scene can reference some assets that are exclusive to that scene, and some assets that are shared with other scenes. I would like the shared assets to be built in one asset bundle, and the scene and its' exclusive assets in another asset bundle. My wish is for the shared assets to be placed in one folder, and each scene and its' exclusive assets to be placed in one folder each, and build one asset bundle per folder.

1. Is it possible to **not** include the references/dependencies in a scene
   when building an asset bundle containing it?
2. Is it possible to specify a **folder** in which to include all assets in the asset bundle (rather than having a scene define it, or marking them specifically as part of an asset bundle in the inspector)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my reading of [Asset Bundle management](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager)

> Dependent Assets will be added to the AssetBundle automatically along with the selected Asset if that dependent Asset **has not been assigned to any AssetBundle** when the AssetBundles are built.

So all you have to do is package those shared assets *first* then package the scenes.